# Multiset MySQL query with complex count

Tags: php, mysql

I got two tables. One table stores meta data for an user based on a "identifier", which is a unique string to identify a visitor.

The other table stores every hit to the website, and if an action is set the action. The "action" can be normal "view", a "download" or a "PDF" (which happens when the user downloads a PDF). Every page is identifier with a post_id for reference.

The structure:

identifier_meta

> - ID
> - meta_key
> - meta_value
> - identifier

**traces**

> - ID
> - created_at
> - identifier
> - ipaddress
> - action
> - post_id

So, I want to run a query which selects al traces that are attached to one or multiple "post_ids", are grouped by the identifier and between a certain timestamp range. I only want records which have any meta present in "identifier_meta" and I want to count all the actions (which may be hardcoded, since there are only 6 actions:

> - download
> - download-word
> - download-pdf
> - view
> - email
> - print

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_traces 
WHERE
    identifier IN ( SELECT identifier FROM wp_identifier_meta )
        AND
    created_at > 0
        AND
    created_at < 102030502
        AND
    (
        post_id = 1
            OR
        post_id = 2
    )
GROUP BY identifier
ORDER BY created_at
```

This gives me traces, between a certain date and time belonging to some posts, but I miss the action counts for the identifier in the resultset... And I frankly don't know how to add that.

Ideally I have resultset where each row contains

> - traces.identifier (string)
> - identifier_meta.name (string (can be empty)
> - identifier_meta.company (string) (can be empty)
> - traces.created_at (date last trace)
> - SUM of total download within this date
> - SUM of total download-word within this date
> - SUM of total download-pdf within this date
> - SUM of total email within this date
> - SUM of total view within this date
> - SUM of total print within this date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a case statement in conjunction with the SUM aggregate function.  Something like this.  I am guessing a little since I do not know the exact nature of your data.

```
SELECT t.identifier,
       im.name,
       im.company,
       t.created_at,
       SUM(CASE WHEN meta_value = 'download' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_downloads,
       SUM(CASE WHEN meta_value = 'download-word' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_downloads,
       SUM(CASE WHEN meta_value = 'download-pdf' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_downloads,
       SUM(CASE WHEN meta_value ='email' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_downloads,
       SUM(CASE WHEN meta_value ='view' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_downloads,
       SUM(CASE WHEN meta_value ='print' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_downloads

FROM wp_traces AS t
     JOIN wp_identifier_meta AS im
     ON t.identifier = im.identifier 
WHERE
    t.created_at > 0
        AND
    t.created_at < 102030502
        AND
    (
        t.post_id = 1
            OR
        t.post_id = 2
    )
GROUP BY t.identifier
ORDER BY created_at
```